# Python 2.7 Bloomberg blpapi import error on Mac OS X Sierra

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, blpapi

After successful installation of the pybgg, when tried to run
$python test_pybbg.py

Got the following error message:
ImportError: No module named blpapi

MacBook:pfinance Allen$ which python

/Users/Allen/anaconda/bin/python

MacBook:pfinance Allen$ python test_pybbg.py

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "test_pybbg.py", line 2, in

```
import pybbg
```

File "/Users/Allen/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pybbg/**init**.py", line 8, in

```
from .pybbg_k import Pybbg
```

File "/Users/Allen/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pybbg/pybbg_k.py", line 8, in

```
import blpapi
```

ImportError: No module named blpapi

I used  $pip list, but failed to see  blpapi from the output list.
Any suggestions on how to fix my problem?

Thanks in advance

## Ps. The followings show my installation log

MacBook:pfinance Allen$ pip install git+https://github.com/hubertrogers/pybbg
Collecting git+https://github.com/hubertrogers/pybbg

Cloning https://github.com/hubertrogers/pybbg to /private/var/folders/c6/7s88m85x0fj7l0zc52y_kcbh0000gn/T/pip-XagRDz-build

Installing collected packages: pybbg
  Running setup.py install for pybbg ... done

Successfully installed pybbg-0.0.1

Based on the post I have set the library links properly;

MacBook:pfinance Allen$ echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
/Users/Allen/pfinance/blpapi_cpp_3.8.1.1/Darwin/

MacBook:pfinance Allen$ echo $BLPAPI_ROOT
/Users/Allen/pfinance/blpapi_cpp_3.8.1.1